# How does external work move heat from cold reservoir to hot?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, heat-engine

From Clausius statement on Wikipedia:
"In a refrigerator, heat flows from cold to hot, but only when forced by an external agent, the refrigeration system."

1. How exactly does the external work make the heat flow from cold to hot?

In diagrams like this, they show the heat leaving the cold reservoir with work being added in the center.

[image]

2. Why would there be heat flowing out the refrigerator before any external work acts on it? Is it due to the refrigerant?

Comment: What is the source of your diagram?

Comment: lealaps, note from the answers given, heat ALWAYS flows from high temperature to low temperature, even in a refrigerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move heat from a colder region to a hotter region, we use a heat engine.

A heat engine manipulates the temperature of a fluid by changing the pressure.

As the refrigerant fluid enters the colder region (from which we mean to extract heat), it passes through a valve into a low pressure pipe (the cooling coil). This causes vaporization, extracting the latent heat of vaporization of the fluid from the air in the colder region. You may have used a compressed gas canister of "canned air" to clean electronics and noticed that both the gas and the canister gets very cold after a few seconds of spraying. Same phenomenon: when liquids vaporize because of a pressure change, they suck heat out of their surroundings.

The refrigerant, now a gas, is pumped into a compressor. The compressor does work on the refrigerant, adding pressure until it liquifies despite its high temperature.

The hot liquid is pumped through a radiator in the warm region. Because the coolant is now hotter than the air, heat flows from the radiator into the air in the warm region.

The process repeats in a continuous flow.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How exactly does the external work make the heat flow from cold to
>    hot?

I'm not a refrigeration expert, but the following attempts to summarize the process.

The external work is done by a compressor. The compressor operates between two heat exchangers, the evaporator coil which is in contact with the low temperature environment removing heat from that environment, and the condenser coil which is in contact with the high temperature environment transferring heat to that environment.

More details:

EVAPORATOR:

The working fluid (refrigerant) entering the evaporator coil is saturated, or nearly saturated, low temperature and pressure liquid, i.e., a fluid that is essentially all liquid at its boiling point. The liquids boiling point temperature is less than the low temperature environment being cooled so that as the liquid moves along the evaporator coil heat transfers from the low temperature environment into the liquid converting the liquid to a gas at constant temperature and pressure.

COMPRESSOR:

The saturated vapor leaving the evaporator coil enters the compressor. The compressor does work compressing the low pressure and temperature vapor to a high temperature and pressure vapor, which enters the condensing coil.

CONDENSER:

The temperature of the vapor entering the condenser coil is now greater than the temperature of the high temperature environment that it is in contact with, resulting in heat transfer out of the vapor to the high temperature environment. As the vapor moves along the coil the heat transfer results in converting the vapor back to a liquid, again at constant temperature and pressure.

EXPANSION VALVE:

The high temperature and pressure saturated liquid leaving the condenser needs to be returned to the evaporator as a low temperature and pressure saturated liquid for the evaporation process to begin. To accomplish this, the expansion valve drops the pressure and temperature of the liquid refrigerant to the desired temperature and pressure at the entry to the evaporator coil. Ideally, this occurs without any heat transfer.

> 2. Why would there be heat flowing out the refrigerator before any
>    external work acts on it? Is it due to the refrigerant?

Because the compressor work is used to move the refrigerant from the evaporator coil to the condenser coil. It's at the coils where the heat transfers occur as explained above. The compressor itself does not transfer heat. But without the compressor, the heat transfer from low to high temperature would not be possible.

Hope this helps.